# How crop some region of image in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, crop

I'm trying do the following code:

```
private void crop(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    int w = 3264;
    int h = 2448;

    String path = "D:images\\upload_final\\030311175258.jpg";

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);

    ImageIO.write(out, "jpg", new File(path));

}
```

But keeps giving me the same error:

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:1230)
    java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(BufferedImage.java:1156)
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My initial guess is that your `(x + w) > image.getWidth()`.

If you print out image.getWidth(), is it 3264? :O

What you're currently doing is this:

```
<-- 3264 ------>
+--------------+
|    orig      | +-- Causing the problem
|              | V
|   +--------------+
|100| overlap  |   |
|   |          |   |
|   |          |   |
+---|----------+   |
    |              |
    |    out       |
    +--------------+
```

If you're trying to trim off the top corner of orig, and just get "overlap" then you need to do

```
BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x, y, w-x, h-y);
```

If you're trying to do this:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|  +-----------+   |
|  |           |   |
|  |           |   |
|  |           |   |
|  |           |   |
|  +-----------+   |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

Then you need to do this:

```
BufferedImage out = image.getSubimage(x, y, w-2*x, h-2*y);
```

Comment: @Valter Updated answer to make it more clear what we're doing.

Comment: thank you so much @glowcoder works perfectly i'm the second approach =)

Comment: @Valter no problem. Ascii art: the whiteboard of Stack Overflow. :-)

Answer (score 5):

For those who just want cropping and other basic image manipulation features on your software I recommend to use an image processing library. Usually the implementations are optimized and stable.

Some Java image processing libraries: [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/), [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net), [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html), [JIU](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jiu/), [JH Labs](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/), [imgscalr](https://github.com/thebuzzmedia/imgscalr).

Another advantage is to keep things simple on your side. You can do a lot of things with just a few lines of code. In the example below, I used [Marvin Framework](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net) for cropping.

**Original:**
[image]

**Cropped:**
[image]

**Source:**

```
MarvinImage image = MarvinImageIO.loadImage("./res/famousFace.jpg");
crop(image.clone(), image, 60, 32, 182, 62);
MarvinImageIO.saveImage(image, "./res/famousFace_cropped.jpg");
```

Comment: cropping is one line of code what are you talking about?? of course you have to promote your library

Comment: @gpasch Sorry If I was not clear about my point. When I recommend to use a library is related to image processing in general, not considering just cropping. Many developers come here looking for a solution. Instead of copying and pasting methods, I recommend to use a library. Cropping is just one line, but resizing, rotation, etc is much more complex to do using just default Java API. I cited 6 frameworks. Of course I used Marvin on my example since it is the one I help to develop and I'm more familiar with. If others see this issue like you after my explanation I'll delete the answer myself.

Comment: @GabrielAmbrósioArchanjo Personally I love the answer (even though I have the checkmark!) I will say that if you helped develop the framework you disclaim that in the answer. =) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/147335